# Netbeans unable to push to GitHub repository. Keeps asking for username and password

Tags: git, github, netbeans

I have a private repository that I usually push my code to. Recently I started a new project and wanted to clone that repository but it kept asking me for my username and password and even if I entered it, it doesn't pass saying incorrect credentials.

I deleted the GitHub repository and recreated it and tried to push my code up again by re-initializing Git but it still doesn't work. I have tried looking around for a solution but so far all not many people have encountered this issue.

I am not using ssh as the url. I am using https://github.com/username/app.git instead.

Comment: Have you ever set up SSH keys for your GitHub account?

Comment: No, initially I thought that was the case but my ssh key section in github is empty

Comment: This repository I am using has been deleted and recreated a few times. I also use the same name each time. It’s just for doing some testing

Comment: I think I'll close it because it suddenly worked. Maybe there was whitespace when I entered my password

Comment: Seems not reproducible, should be closed

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't support that. You need to setup a token.

See https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

This worked for me